# WooCommerce tag returning customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In our store, during checkout for every customer we create account automatically if it doesn’t already exist with same email. Now I’m looking for a way to somehow display label tag or little notice on orders list if it comes from already existing customer (returning) because these orders are handled a little differently.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this snippet adds a column to orders list page in woocommerce backend and checks if customer is returning or not

```php
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'shalior_wc_set_custom_edit_post_columns',99,1 );
function shalior_wc_set_custom_edit_post_columns($columns) {
    $columns['is-returning'] = __( 'Is returning?', 'your_text_domain' );
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'shalior_wc_is_returning', 99, 2 );
function shalior_wc_is_returning( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'is-returning':
            $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
            $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
            $orders_count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );
            echo $orders_count > 1 ? "Yes" : "NO" ;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: I make a very simple checkout form i don't register customers and also don't get emails what I have is only the phone number.
so how can i check if the customer is returning using the phone number?

no matter how many times he order if the phone number is same then it should add tag or column on order list page that this is returning customer